# add image and title to the navigationbar of tab based application

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to add image and background image to the navigation bar of tab based application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarimg.png"]];
```

Comment: can I add a title too at this case

Comment: you can add a title but it will only serve as en identifier for the navigation buttons (i.e. if you push another viewcontroller in the navigationcontroller, the back button will have that title).

Other than that, this titleview replaces the UIView that normally contains the label with the title on the navigation bar, so you should add text with your title in the image if you want it to sow there

Comment: @Ali You should do it in viewWillAppear. Other than that, check that you have added the image to the project, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"your_image_name"];
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

For setting title you can try

```
self.title = @"your title";
```

Comment: it's autoomatically added to the view , I can access it using self.navigationitem